# Explanation of evaluation for this Scheme procedure using lambdas

Tags: scope, scheme, racket, evaluation, r5rs

I was wondering how the following code evaluates to 3.

```
(define (foo y) ((lambda (x) y) ((lambda (y)(* y y)) y))) 

(foo 3)
```

I have been looking at it for a while and cannot seem to understand why the evaluation does not result in 9. Could someone provide a detailed step by step instruction on how this evaluates to 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by indenting the code in a way that it's easier to understand:

```
(define (foo y)
  ((lambda (x) y)
   ((lambda (y) (* y y))
    y)))
```

Now let's evaluate it, from the inside-out:

```
(define (foo y)
  ((lambda (x) y)
   ((lambda (y) (* y y))
    3))) ; pass the parameter

(define (foo y)
  ((lambda (x) y)
   (* 3 3))) ; evaluate innermost lambda

(define (foo y)
  ((lambda (x) y) 9)) ; pass the result of evaluation
```

Aha! that's where we get the `3`. Even though we're passing a `9` as parameter (bound to `x`), we're simply returning the value of the outermost `y` parameter, which was `3` all along:

```
=> 3
```

Comment: Oh That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `let` re-writing,

```
(define (foo y) ((lambda (x) y) ((lambda (y)(* y y)) y))) 

(foo 3)
=
(let ([y 3])                                 ; by application
  ((lambda (x) y) ((lambda (y)(* y y)) y))) 
=
(let ([y 3])
  (let ([x ((lambda (y)(* y y)) y)])       ; by application
     y ))
=
(let ([y 3])
  (let ([x ((lambda (z)(* z z)) y)])     ; by alpha-renaming
     y ))
=
(let ([y 3])
  (let ([x (let ([z y])                ; by application
               (* z z))])
     y ))
=
(let ([y 3])
  (let ([x  (* y y)])                ; by let-elimination
     y ))
=
(let ([y 3])
  (let ([x 9])                     ; by expression evaluation
     y ))
=
(let ([y 3]) 
     y  )                        ; by let-elimination
=
3                              ; by let-elimination
```

As you can see, the nested `(lambda (y)(* y y))` is situated in a nested scope, not affecting the `y` which is finally returned, but only `x`, which value, *9*, is evaluated and then discarded.